# NoSuchElement exception when using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception, system.in

I'm trying to get input from the console a second time within the program using `Scanner`s but when calling a second `Scanner` in another method it’s coming up with NoSuchElement exception.

If I remove `startMenu()` from running `fileReader()` it works, however for some reason after running it throws the exception.

```
    public class Garden {
    public static final Garden GARDEN = new Garden();
    //variable declartaions removed
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (null != args && 0 < args.length) {
            GARDEN.fileName = args[0].trim();
        }
        if (GARDEN.fileName != null) {
            GARDEN.fileReader(GARDEN.fileName);
        } else {
            GARDEN.fileReader();
        }

        GARDEN.startMenu();
        int mainI = 0;
        while (mainI != 1000000) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(0);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            GARDEN.daysWeather();
            GARDEN.anotherDay();
            mainI++;
        }
    }


    protected void fileReader() { // asks for file name for config file
        System.out.println("Enter File Name Please");
        Scanner cmdReader = null;
        String cmdInput = null;
        try {
            cmdReader = new Scanner(System.in);
            cmdInput = cmdReader.nextLine();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException noSuchElement) {
            noSuchElement.printStackTrace();
            fileReader();  //throwing error here
        }

        //code removed
    }



    protected void startMenu() {// modified code from ATM lab (week2)
    int selected = 0;
        //code removed 
        Scanner climateScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Select a number 1-4");
        selected = climateScanner.nextInt();
        switch (selected) {
        case 1: // semiarid
            weatherType = 10; //10% chance to rain
            climateScanner.close();
            break;
        case 2: // arid
            weatherType = 20; //5% chance to rain
            climateScanner.close();
            break;
        case 3:
            weatherType = 50; //2% chance to rain
            tropicalWeather = true;
            climateScanner.close(); 
            break;
        case 4:
            weatherType = 20;//5% chance to rain 
            storming = true;
            climateScanner.close();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Input try again");
            startMenu(); //using Recursion to ask for input again
            break;
        }
        //code removed
    }
}
```

Comment: GARDEN is the singleton created didn't think this is the problem as it works with GARDEN.fileReader() when GARDEN.startMenu() isnt called

Answer (score 1):

```
 GARDEN.startMenu();// method id not a static one.
```

you can't access that in this way. you have to initialize the class or make your method static. and also what is `GARDEN` ??

Ok now you are edited your code.

Again

```
 GARDEN.fileReader(GARDEN.fileName); // you are parsing input argument 
                                // But method in your class is no argument method
```

Comment: Or make `startMenu` *static*.

Comment: fileReader(GARDEN.fileName) is just another instance of fileReader() that instead of asking for a fileName takes it from when the program is started in console java Garden testA.txt will run fileReader(fileName)   java Garden will run fileReader()

Comment: the difference between the two fileReader() methods is that one that takes the parameter gets the fileName from the parameter while the one without a parameter gets it from console input via the scanner (not sure if thats what you mean by do i have another method in same name)

Comment: @user1642671 I suggest you to use `debuger` . Then easily you will realize the issue

Comment: I have tried it gets cmdReader = new Scanner(System.in); and then throws exception is there something i have to do with System.in after every use?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was 2 different Scanner (one in startMenu() and one in readFile()) changed it so there was a Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in) in class variables and then calling scanner.nextLine() from within the method